# ForegroundService that waits for incoming SMS in Android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, foreground-service

I do not really know how to tackle my problem.

I start a Foreground service in Android. Within that service I wait for 2 minutes and now I would like to listen to incoming SMS.
If within 2 minutes no incoming SMS is received, I would like to have a text to speech message.

My Foreground service is running perfectly so far, however, I do not know how to tackle the problem if no SMS is received or is received?

First, I thought about sending a Broadcastreceiver manually, then waiting for 2 minutes and if within those 2 minutes an SMS is received, everything is fine.

However, I would like to react to an incoming SMS immediately and I do not know how to do that!

Maybe someone can point me to the right solution?

Here is my code for the Foreground service:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    loadSharedPreferences(StaticFields.WAIT_MINUTES);
    createNotificationChannel();
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,
            0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT |
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT | PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);
    notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID)
            .setContentTitle("No SMS retrieved within the last " + counter + " seconds")
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setOngoing(true)
            .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background);

    notification = notificationBuilder.build();

    startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);

    waitForXMinutes*=60;
    while (counter <= waitForXMinutes) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            manager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID /* ID of notification */,
                    notificationBuilder.setContentTitle("No parkingticket for " + counter + " seconds").build());
            counter++;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    stopSelf();
    return START_NOT_STICKY;
}
```

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

For the moment I solved the problem with the BroadcastReceiver but not the problem with the not receiving SMS.

If no SMS is received at all, a voice message should be played!

Here is my code. Within the service I created the BroadcastReceiver

```
private final BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if(action.equals("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED")){
            Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
            SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
            String msg_from;
            if (bundle != null){
                try{
                    Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
                    msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
                    for(int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++){
                        msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);
                        msg_from = msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
                        String msgBody = msgs[i].getMessageBody();
                        if(!msgBody.contains("Zuletzt gebuchter Parkschein")) {
                            textToSpeech = new TextToSpeech(getApplicationContext(), new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onInit(int status) {
                                    if (status != TextToSpeech.ERROR) {
                                        textToSpeech.setLanguage(Locale.GERMAN);
                                        textToSpeech.speak("Es wurde kein Parkschein in den letzten " + waitForXMinutes + " Sekunden gebucht",
                                                TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null, "0");
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
                }catch(Exception e){
                    Log.d("Exception caught",e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

And in the onCreate method I registered the BroadcastReceiver

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");

    registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
}
```

Still pending is my problem, if no SMS is received at all.
I am still looking for a solution where my "internal" Broadcastreceiver gets triggered all the time, even if no SMS is received.